# MongoDB: using aggregate Multilevel unwind and group

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the multiple collections/tables in MongoDB. For simplicity, I'm writing the pseudo code for understanding the schema

`TableName (Column1, Column2, ...)`

**Schema**

```
Report (name)
Criterias (name, title)
Entries (finding, criteria_id, report_id)
EntriesImages (entry_id, image)
Evidences (comment, entriesImage_id, user_id)
Users (name, email, password)
```

I am able to get the data till the Evidences with the following query/code

```
var entries = await Entries.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      criteria: criteria._id,
      report: report._id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'entriesimages',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'entry_id',
      as: 'entriesimages',
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$entriesimages',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'evidences',
      localField: 'entriesimages._id',
      foreignField: 'entriesImage_id',
      as: 'entriesimages.evidences',
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      entry: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
      entriesimages: { $push: '$entriesimages' },
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: ['$entry', { entriesimages: '$entriesimages' }]
      }
    }
  },
]);
```

Now, as I mentioned in schema, there is `user_id` in the evidences table and I want to populate the user for each evidence too.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could try a `"$lookup"` in a `"pipeline"` with `"$lookup": { "from": "evidences", ... }`.  I.e., a nested `"$lookup"`.

Comment: A document oriented NoSQL database like MongoDB is not a relational database, you may review your database design. The number of collections in MongoDB is typically much lower than the number of tables in according RDBMS.